# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error in B3

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

activity = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=10, # Increase number of epochs if you have sufficient hardware

```
      validation_data=val_gen,
      
      verbose = 1
```

)
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\BLRCSE~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15312/3305335964.py", line 1, in 
activity = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=10, # Increase number of epochs if you have sufficient hardware

File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/sequential_1/dense_5/MatMul/MatMul' defined at (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console_*main**.py", line 23, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 328, in main
kernel.start()
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
self.io_loop.start()
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
handle._run()
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 457, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 446, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 353, in dispatch_shell
await result
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 648, in execute_request
reply_content = await reply_content
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 353, in do_execute
res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2901, in run_cell
result = self._run_cell(
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2947, in _run_cell
return runner(coro)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in *pseudo_sync_runner
coro.send(None)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3172, in run_cell_async
has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3364, in run_ast_nodes
if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async*=asy)):
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15312/1931121224.py", line 1, in 
activity = model.fit(train_gen,
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1384, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 863, in train_step
self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 530, in minimize
grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 583, in _compute_gradients
grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
File "C:\Users\BLRCSE513-WS01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 464, in _get_gradients
grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
Node: 'gradient_tape/sequential_1/dense_5/MatMul/MatMul'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,2], In[1]: [120,1]
[[{{node gradient_tape/sequential_1/dense_5/MatMul/MatMul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_47374]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was classifying the images and when i tried to find the classification report and metrics in keras the above output generated.

Answer (score 1):

If memory growth is enabled for a PhysicalDevice, the runtime initialization will not allocate all memory on the device. Memory growth cannot be configured on a PhysicalDevice with virtual devices configured.

**For example:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
try:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
except:
  # Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
  pass
```